# Compute $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{s+k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

Anyone can help me finding this summation:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{s+k}.
$$
Where there is a similar one with known answer
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{s-k}=\dfrac{n!}{s(s-1)(s-2)...(s-n)}=\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(s-n)}{\Gamma(s+1)}.
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that, for every positive $s$, $$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{s+k}=
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\int_0^1t^{s+k-1}dt=\int_0^1t^{s-1}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}t^kdt$$ hence
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{s+k}=\int_0^1t^{s-1}(1-t)^ndt=\mathrm{Beta}(s,n+1)=\frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(s+n+1)}.$$

Comment: Yes, Laplace transform in disguise...

Comment: That's equal to:$$\frac{(s-1)!n!}{(s+n)!}$$for anyone who doesn't know about the Gamma function. (That can probably be rewritten in terms of binomial coefficients.) (It should be noted, by the way, that—once this equation is known—one can also prove it by induction.)

Answer (score 2):

Introduce the rational function $f(s)$ with poles at $s=0,-1,-2,\ldots -n:$
$$f(s) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \frac{1}{s+k}.$$
Now observe that
$$\mathrm{Res}_{s=-k} f(s) = (-1)^k {n\choose k}.$$

Compare with $g(s)$ given by
$$g(s) = \frac{n!}{s(s+1)(s+2)\cdots(s+n)}.$$
The poles of $g(s)$ are the same as the poles of $f(s)$ and both are simple, with residue
$$\mathrm{Res}_{s=-k} g(s) =
\frac{n!}{(-k)(-k+1)\cdots(-k+k-1)(-k+k+1)(-k+k+2)\cdots(-k+n)}.$$
This simplifies to
$$\mathrm{Res}_{s=-k} g(s) =
\frac{n! (-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!} =  (-1)^k {n\choose k}.$$

We conclude that $f(s) = g(s).$

Answer (score 0):

prove by induction that
$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-10^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{s+k}={\frac {n!\,s!}{s \left( n+s \right) !}}$